# Derivation of Q(y) by using the definition of density function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $Y$ be a Gaussian random variable with a density $Q(y)$. We would like to derive $Q(y)$ by using the definition of the density function, the probability of $Y$ is contained in the interval $(y,y+dy)$ is given by
$$Q(y)dy=\int_{y}^{y+dy}P(x)dx$$

where $P(x)$ is the density function of $x$.

My question is how is this differentiation? As far I know, the definition of differentiation is $\frac{d}{dy}Q(y)$.

I just don't see the equality above.

Any ideas? Links or references of where I can find this? Something I wasn't paying attention in my calculus' classes?

Thank you.

Comment: The formula is wrong . Where did you find this?

Comment: There also seems to be some redundancy/confusion. You write “with a density $Q(y)$.” But then set it equal to the integral “[...] where $P(x)$ is the density function of [sic] $x$”. Reminder: density functions do not represent probabilities, they represent probabilities per unit (they may exceed $1$ *unlike proper probabilities* obtained from computing CDFs)